# How can a dispose method be hidden?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm using a third party API dll, bloomberg SAPI for those who know / have access to it.

Here's my problem:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IDisposable     
{ //this is from mscorlib 2.0.0.0 - standard System.IDisposable
    void Dispose();
}

public abstract class AbstractSession : IDisposable {}//method signatures and comments

public class Session : AbstractSession {} //method signatures and comments (from assembly metadata)
```

All of the above is from the F12 / Go to definition / object browser in VS2010. Now when i try and use this code:

```
(new Session()).Dispose();
```

This does not compile... standard compiler error - no definition / extension method 'Dispose' could be found.

How is this possible??? They've made an assembly and explicitly edited it's metadata?

I don't know if it's legally possible to hide (to exclusion) a public method....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx). The class is written like:

```
class Session : IDisposable {
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

You can only call it if your variable is of type `IDisposable`, like:

```
IDisposable mySession = new Session();
mySession.Dispose();
```

Or by casting:

```
((IDisposable)mySession).Dispose();
```

Or with a `using` statement, which automatically calls `Dispose` when it completes (this is specific only to `IDisposable`, and is generally a best practice for disposing any object which implements this interface):

```
using (var session = new Session()) { }
```

Comment: Aaarrgggh ! nice. I'd never used the explicit implementations so didn't know that you need an interface cast to use it. Thanks !

Comment: Explicit interface implementation is usually not necessary, but there are some times when it's nice, like when you want to force your fellow developers to code by interface instead of implementation. And some times when it's necessary, like when you need to implement two different interfaces which have an identical member signature that you need to implement two different ways.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. As you mentioned, you rarely need to use the explicit unless method names are clashing, so this is the first time i saw this in production code. Wonder what clashed with DISPOSE ! :)

Comment: @JoeEnos - spot on. One common case of explicit interface implementation is when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`; because it derives from the non-generic `IEnumerable`, you have to implement both versions of GetEnumerator and they can step on each others' toes. So, the best practice is to explicitly implement the non-generic method, so it's only called when the collection is being treated as such.

Comment: @KeithS Good call, I was trying to think of one that conflicted, that's a good example. Personally, I just always do explicit, unless there's a reason not to.

Comment: @Vivek - Well, since this class is registered for COM interop, there can be other reasons besides name clashing. Methods like Dispose() that deal primarily with .NET memory management may only have value to a consumer that also lives in the .NET sandbox; unmanaged code would have other ways to destroy the reference, as would code in a different managed runtime like the JVM. So, by requiring you to explicitly cast to IDisposable to call Dispose, the code basically forces you to prove you're in .NET-land.